# How can I implement the click edit, select item and remove feature in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In the screenshot included below, when user clicks on Edit button on the header, the component with text X saved to cart needs to change. Basically a checkbox would appear in right to all the components containing X saved to cart. How can I implement this.

One way I thought to do this is when user clicks Edit button on the header, the component having X saved to cart would be informed in some way then I can change the view of the component.

Is this right approach to implement the edit functionality? If not how can this be done?

P.S. I am not using Redux. 
Code provided below the screenshot.

[image]

Code

Saved Deal Page (This page is displayed when heart icon on the tab bar is clicked)

```
export const SavedDealsPageStack = createStackNavigator ({
    SavedDeals: {
        screen : savedDealsPage,
        navigationOptions:{
            header: <SavedDealHeader />
        }        
    },
    DealsDetailPage:{
        screen : DealsDetailPageStack,
    },
},
{
    navigationOptions:{
        header: null
    }
});
```

SavedDealHeader Component

export default class SavedDealHeader extends Component {

```
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.savedDealHeaderContainer}>
                <View style={styles.headerComponentDivider}>
                    <View style={styles.headerTitleContainer}>
                        <Text style={textStyles.savedDealHeaderTitle}>Temp List</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{paddingRight:edgePadding}}>
                        <Text style={textStyles.editButton}>Edit</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

List Items are being rendered using the FlatList Component of React native

The Card component is called to render each item in the list (This component is in a separate JS page located in a different directory).

Comment: Without seeing any code besides the images people can't help you. Share your code, share what have you tried up to now and where you stuck.

Comment: you can pass an array of 'saved to card' products id and check equality with products in list

Answer (score 1):

A top level navigation component can track the current mode in its state. Then, if you pass this 'mode' variable down to each lower component via props, when the state.mode changes, the props of the lower components change also, causing them to re-render with a checkbox showing. You can then further add add any conditionals to only show the checkbox if it has been checked, or however you wish. Please see below for a simplified example of data flowing down into the lower components.

```js
function SaveCartCheckBox(props) {    
    if(!props.mode){
      return false;
    }
    return (
      <div className="item">
        <h3>X Saved to Cart</h3>
        <input 
        type="checkbox"
        defaultChecked={props.saved}
        {...(!props.saved ? {checked:false} : {})}        
        onClick={() => props.onClick()}
        />
        </div>
    );
}

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        editmode: true,
        savedItems : {
          1 : false,
          2 : false,
          3 : true
        }
      };

    }
    
    saveItem(itemNo) {    
      let savedItems = this.state.savedItems;
      savedItems[itemNo] = !savedItems[itemNo];
      this.setState({
        savedItems
      });
    }
    
    
    changeMode(){
      const currentMode = this.state.editmode;      
      this.setState({
        editmode: !currentMode
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <button onClick={() => {this.changeMode()}}>Change Mode</button>
              {
                  Object.keys(this.state.savedItems).map((index,itemState) => {                         return (
                      <SaveCartCheckBox key={index} 
                      onClick={() => this.saveItem(index)} 
                      saved={this.state.savedItems[index]} 
                      mode={this.state.editmode}
                      />
                  )})
              }     
          </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.item {
  display:block;
  border:2px solid grey;
  background:lightgreen;
  margin:0.2em;
  text-align:center;
}
input[type='checkbox']{
  zoom:2;
  position:relative;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to make my card component aware that the edit button has been clicked? Edit is present in the Navigation header where as the card component is a component being used by my savedDealPage. Refer to the SavedDealPageStack code above.

Comment: Hi @Chetan, you could send a click handler into the 'Navigation header' component, keeping the state of the edit mode in the parent SavedDealPageStack and then pass it around to whichever components need it. If you need to keep track of each components checkbox state, I've updated the code.